# finalizecache and cachedir undefined when using minted with tcblisting

Tags: minted, tcblisting

I am using minted to display python code and I need to use `finalizecache` and `cachedir` to be able to submit my code somewhere else and compile without using `--shell-escape`, which is disabled for security reasons. However, when I create a `newtcblisting` and pass these parameters I get a keyval error saying that these parameters are undefined. This is how I define a `newtcblisting`:

```
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins}
\usepackage{caption}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\newtcblisting{sourcecode}[1][python]{
  colback=Gray,
  listing engine=minted,
  minted language=#1,
%  minted options={finalizecache,cachedir=.}, % Package keyval Error: finalizecache and cachedir are undefined.
  listing only,
  skin=tile,
  width=0.8\textwidth
}

\captionsetup[table]{name=Code}
```

Then I create my code like this:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{sourcecode}
from hiclass import LocalClassifierPerNode
from hiclass.metrics import f1
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# define mock data
X_train = X_test = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
Y_train = Y_test = [
    ["Animal", "Mammal", "Cat"],
    ["Animal", "Reptile", "Turtle"],
]

# Use random forest classifiers for every node
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
lcpn = LocalClassifierPerNode(local_classifier=rf)
lcpn.fit(X_train, Y_train)  # Train model
predictions = lcpn.predict(X_test)  # Predict test data

# Print hierarchical F-score
print(f"f1: {f1(y_true=Y_test, y_pred=predictions)}")
    \end{sourcecode}
    \caption{Example on how to use \texttt{HiClass} to train and evaluate a hierarchical classifier.}
    \label{code}
\end{table}
```

Which gives me the output below:

[image: Code generated with minted]

Am I doing something wrong when creating this tcblisting? Other parameters such as linenos work fine.

Edit: question also asked on [issue #208](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/208).

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should add links to all other versions to all your questions! Otherwise you risk wasting the time of the users willing to help you as well as the time of future users with the same problem.

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75160711/finalizecache-and-cachedir-undefined-when-using-minted-with-tcblisting

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Apologies. I deleted the other post since it is more appropriate to have it here.